# Resetting HTML5 validations

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, validation

Preface: I've looked for solutions on SO, but I think this may just be a me issue so I am not sure.

I am attempting to use HTML5 validations for client side validations on a form. I have custom validation error messages on the fields as well.

The issue I am having is when the user clicks submit on the form and the validation fails, then the user ***corrects*** the issue; the validation still fails.

I am unable to pass the validations even if the user corrects the issue in the form.

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :client_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :talent_id, value: @profile.user.id %>
  <div style='margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:1em'>
    <div>
      <p class='large-title upcase'>Assign Proposal to Production</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <%= select_tag :production_title,options_for_select(current_user.productions.map {|p| [p.title]}.uniq),{class: 'standard-text-field', prompt: "Choose Existing Production"} %>
    </div>
    <p>or</p>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <%= text_field_tag :new_production_title,nil, {class: 'standard-text-field', placeholder:"Create a New Production", maxlength: 45} %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <hr style='margin-top:6.5em;'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <%= select_tag :booking_templates, options_for_select(current_user.sent_bookings.where(template: true).map {|p| [p.job_title]}.uniq),{class: 'standard-text-field', prompt: "Choose Booking Template"} %>
    </div>
    <p>or create a new booking</p>
    <div>
      <p class='large-title upcase'>Job Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <%= f.text_field :job_title, { class: 'standard-text-field', placeholder:"Job Title", required: true, oninvalid: "this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a job title')" } %>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
      <%= f.text_field :d_start, { class: 'standard-text-field', required: true, oninvalid: "this.setCustomValidity('Please select a date')" } %>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
      <%= f.text_field :d_end, { class: 'standard-text-field', required: true, oninvalid: "this.setCustomValidity('Please select a date')"} %>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
      <%= text_field :shown_amount,nil, {class: 'standard-text-field', id: 'shown-amount', placeholder:"Total Amount (USD)", required: true, oninvalid: "this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid amount')", style: 'text-align:right'} %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :amount, id: 'booking_amount' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class='large-title upcase'>Choose all that apply</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <%= f.text_area :job_description, class: 'standard-text-field standard-large-text-field', placeholder:"Job Description", required: true, oninvalid: "this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a brief description')" %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.submit "Request to Book", class: 'modal-submit-button upcase', id: 'send-request' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My thought process is that there should be some js way that I could reset the validation if the validation does not pass, but not sure. Any help would be appreciated.